# How to make key value by explode and arrange matching key values into one key?

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I am recently facing a practical problem.I am working with ajax form submission and there has been some checkboxes.I need all checkboxes with same name as key value pair.Suppose there is 4 checkboxes having `name` attribute `=checks` so i want something like `$arr['checks'] = array(value1, value2, ...)`

So i am getting my ajax $_POST code as suppose like: `name=alex&checks=code1&checks=code2&checks=code3`

I am using below code to make into an array

```
public function smdv_process_option_data(){
    $dataarray = array();
    $newdataarray = array();
    $new = array();
    $notices = array();
    $data = $_POST['options']; // data received by ajax

    $dataarray = explode('&', $data);
    foreach ($dataarray as $key => $value) {
        $i = explode('=', $value);
        $j = 1;
        if(array_key_exists($i[0], $newdataarray)){
            if( !is_array($newdataarray[$i[0]]) ){
                array_push($new, $newdataarray[$i[0]]);

            }else{
                array_push($new, $i[1]);

            }
            $newdataarray[$i[0]] = $new;
        }else{
            $newdataarray[$i[0]] = $i[1];
        }

    }


    die($newdataarray);
}
```

Here i want `$newdataarray` as like below

```
array(
   'name' => 'alex',
   'checks => array(code1, code2, code3),
)
```

But any how I am missing 2nd value from `checks` key array.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you only need to do two explode syntaxes.
The first on is to get the name and here I explode on `&` and then on `name=` in order to isolate the name in the string.
The checks is an explode of `&checks=` if you omit the first item with array_slice.

```
$str = 'name=alex&checks=code1&checks=code2&checks=code3';

$name = explode("name=", explode("&", $str)[0])[1];
// alex

$checks = array_slice(explode("&checks=", $str), 1);
// ["code1","code2","code3"]
```

https://3v4l.org/TefuG

Answer (score 1):

> So i am getting my ajax $_POST code as suppose like: name=alex&checks=code1&checks=code2&checks=code3

Use `parse_str` instead.

https://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

> parse_str ( string $encoded_string [, array &$result ] ) : void
>   Parses encoded_string as if it were the query string passed via a URL and sets variables in the current scope (or in the array if result is provided).

```
$s = 'name=alex&checks=code1&checks=code2&checks=code3';

parse_str($s, $r);

print_r($r);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [name] => alex
    [checks] => code3
)
```

You may think this is wrong because there is only one `checks` but technically the string is incorrect.

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/769f4ee3d2d24aa4ac5cf7440ddcf79a850d29d4)

You shouldn't have to post process this data if it's sent correctly, as that is not included in the question, I can only make assumptions about it's origin.

If your manually creating it, I would suggest using `serialize()` on the form element for the data for AJAX.  Post processing this is just a **band-aid** and adds unnecessary complexity.

If it's from a source outside your control, you'll have to parse it manually (as you attempted).

For example the correct way that string is encoded is this:

```
name=alex&checks[]=code1&checks[]=code2&checks[]=code3
```

Which when used with the above code produces the desired output.

```
Array
(
    [name] => alex
    [checks] => Array
        (
            [0] => code1
            [1] => code2
            [2] => code3
        )

)
```

So is the problem here, or in the way it's constructed...

**UPDATE**

I felt obligated to give you the manual parsing option:

```
$str = 'name=alex&checks=code1&checks=code2&checks=code3';
$res = [];

foreach(explode('&',$str) as $value){
    //PHP 7 array destructuring 
    [$key,$value] = explode('=', $value);

    //PHP 5.x list()
    //list($key,$value) = explode('=', $value);

    if(isset($res[$key])){
        if(!is_array($res[$key])){
            //convert single values to array
            $res[$key] = [$res[$key]];
        }
        $res[$key][] = $value;
    }else{
        $res[$key] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($res);
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2b09168cb949b6f4fc291e47e6cc4ee211d1ab93)

The above code is not specific to your keys, which is a good thing.  And should handle any string formatted this way.  If you do have the proper array format mixed in with this format you can add a bit of additional code to handle that, but it can become quite a challenge to handle all the use cases of `key[]`  For example these are all valid:

```
 key[]=value&key[]=value //[key => [value,value]]
 key[foo]=value&key[bar]=value //[key => [foo=>value,bar=>value]]
 key[foo][]=value&key[bar][]=value&key[bar][]=value //[key => [foo=>[value]], [bar=>[value,value]]]
```

As you can see that can get out of hand real quick, so I hesitate to try to accommodate that if you don't need it.

Cheers!

Comment: You'll lose one of the checks as you would with POST or GET.  It should be `'name=alex&checks[]=code1&checks[]=code2&checks[]=code3'`

Comment: I am aware of that.  The problem is in the construction of that string as it doesn't follow the standard for how it would be posted normally.  The same would happen with GET or POST.  Rather or not you can post that the way it should be is another matter.  In anycase you shouldn't need to process that data if it was posted correctly using `form.serialize()` for the data instead of constructing it manually or whatever made it.  Doing so is a bandaid for the real issue.